# TIMEOUT - Módulo Wifi ESP8266 Arduino

Tags: arduino

Resulta que había acabado mi proyecto el cual usa este módulo, todo funciona bien hasta que un día al volver a probarlo había dejado de funcionar el ESP8266. El error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
[WiFiEsp] Initializing ESP module
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] Cannot initialize ESP module
```

Recalco que el proyecto ha estado funcionando perfectamente y conectado al punto de acceso Wifi sin problemas. He probado con otro módulo ESP8266, con otra placa Arduino UNO incluso distintos cables pero nada...ha sido de la noche a la mañana cuando el programa ha dejado de funcionar.

Uso las siguientes librerías:

```
#include "WiFiEsp.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(6, 5); // RX, TX
```

Y para conectarlo a la Wifi:

```
// Inicializo el módulo WiFi
Serial1.begin(9600);
WiFi.init(&Serial1);
// Me conecto a la red
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
```

Incluso el módulo emitía un parpadeo azul que ha dejado de iluminarse, tanto en el viejo como en el nuevo módulo que compré.

Comment: El módulo esp8266 suele dar problemas x la alimentación. Como lo tienes conectado? Se que el arduino mini da 50ma a 3,3v en la salida y eso no es suficiente si tienes más cosas conectadas. Has probado a alimentarlo con una fuente externa? Revisa también el tx y rx, y si puedes muestra un esquema o foto de cómo lo tienes conectado

Comment: Hola Angel, el arduino esta conectado a 3.3V los pines CH_PD, GPIO2 y Vcc, el RX y el TX al pin 6 y 5 respectivamente. Estos últimos pines emulan la conexión serial por software. El proyecto además tiene una pantalla LCD, un led RGB y Shield USB al que conecto un lector de código de barras (como lo de los supermercados). He probado a ponerlo en 5 V pero se calienta muchísimo además de que tampoco funciona.

Comment: me he explicado mal. Me referia a que probaras el arduino con una fuente y el esp8266 con otra distinta (no utilices la salida de 3.3v del propio arduino). Tampoco se te ocurra ponerlo a 5v, que como dices, seguro que lo quemas (el esp8266, claro) :)

Comment: Qué podría utilizar como fuente externa y cuánto voltaje necesitaría?

Comment: Por lo que se ve es problema de la alimentación. Un ESP8266 que se conecta a una WiFi tiene picos de corriente de hasta 200 mA sin embargo, si lo conectas a Arduino no será capaz de suministrar esta corriente. Te recomiendo que utilices una fuente de alimentación externa. Mira este tutorial que te aclarará muchas cosas [Guía ESP-01 ESP8266](https://programarfacil.com/podcast/como-configurar-esp01-wifi-esp8266/)

Comment: ¿Qué pines usan la pantalla LCD, el LED y la placa USB? Es probable que tengas colisión en alguno. ¿Qué tipo de ESP8266 estás usando? No dices nada acerca de la conexión de los pines GND, GPIO-0 y el reset, pero el GPIO-2 lo has conectado a 3.3v.

Answer (score -1):

Algunos módulos wifi tienen un led para las comunicaciones serie. Si existe comunicación serie pues este parpadea. Si en tu caso, utilizas el mismo código, con el mismo módulo, con la misma fuente y no funciona la comunicación y el led que indica la comunicación serie no parpadea, lo más normal es que el problema lo tengas con el rúter (Entiendo, por lo que dices que el ESP se conecta como en modo estación (ST) y el rúter será el punto de acceso (AP). Luego lo más normal es que, de alguna forma, el rúter bloquee el acceso del ESP y éste funcione correctamente. Exactamente no se qué hace tu diseño, pero en cualquier caso, parece que no tienes comunicación. Deberás comprobar los parámetros típicos de una WLAN tanto del rúter como del ESP: TCP/UDP, IP fija o DHCP, entrar en la parametrización del rúter (en el navegador poner 192.168.1.1 generalmente) y comprobar con el rango de IPs con las que se puede trabajar y todas estas cosas.

Por otro lado, el siempre debes mirar el datasheet "https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2471/0A-ESP8266__Datasheet__EN_v4.3.pdf" del dispositivo que uses, al menos sus características eléctricas. Usando la técnica ensayo y error vas a romper muchos componentes.